# Spring Data: what problems could I have if I replace CrudRepository with JpaRepository?

Tags: spring-data

I have a few repository classes. Initially they all extend CrudRepository. For the need to return pageable records, I have made one repository class extend JpaRepository, which makes offers more than just pageable results.

Now I am thinking about replacing all CrudRepository with JpaRepository, no matter whether there is a need for a repository class at this moment.

Are there any runtime issues such as memory, speed, etc?

Thanks for any input!

Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need only pagination abstraction, consider using [`PagingAndSortingRepository`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/PagingAndSortingRepository.html) instead [`JpaRepository`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaRepository.html). `JpaRepository` add some functionality that is specific to JPA then perhaps it is not necessary for you.

In terms of memory and speed issues, it is not relevant in most cases.

As it is not in-memory pagination (such as in [`SimpleJpaRepository`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/support/SimpleJpaRepository.html)), you will not have problems with memory in this case. If you are not using JPA repository implementation, you will note only the JPA overhead, still slightly in most cases.

For pagination, an additional query is necessary to count the records, so we have a small overhead.

`SimpleJpaRepository` has a JPA implementation for `PagingAndSortingRepository` methods. You can write a custom implementation using JDBC, for example. See [this](https://gist.github.com/criminy/1206700) gist of an implementation example of `PagingAndSortingRepository` using `JdbcTemplate`

Overall I believe it is this :)

Comment: Just wanted to add that there's absolutely no difference in overhead whether you extend `CrudRepository`, `PagingAndSortingRepository` or `JpaRepository`. The interface merely control which methods get exposed to clients. The underlying implementation will always be `SimpleJpaRepository` for JPA. Beyond that, I second the opinion to stay away from `JpaRepository` as long as possible so that you don't accidentally tie your repository clients to store specific API.